# Custom TableViewController tableView() method not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

Here is my custom `TableViewController` class.

I inserted a print statement in `viewDidLoad` and `tableView` methods

`viewDidLoad` was printed to the console but `tableView` was not

I made sure to add the identifier `Device Cell` in the attributes editor, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController { 

    // ... some code

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewDidLoad")

    }

    // ... some code

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = 
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: "Device Cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        print("tableView")

        let device = mWifiDevices[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = device.mIpAddress

        return cell
    }


    // ... some code  
}
```

Comment: do you have any cells? show us a code where you set how many of them should be there

Comment: @Lu_ You're right, i forgot to do that!

Comment: are you reloading the UITableView?  What about setting the number of items in the tableView?

Comment: Yep, that was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doh! The solution was simply a matter of adding the row and section count getters

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return mWifiDevices.count
}
```